# boost interprocess rbtree_best_fit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

[image]

I use managed_shared_memory and unordered_map
set 3 million records, per record about 1100bytes, total about 3GB data
when set success, I clear the map mmediately, but it crash

Comment: Please post actual code (i.e. copy and paste the text), not images.

Comment: The code is too much. I think it's not about the code. When I write  a lot of data, the system flush data in backend when I clear data(not flush immediately).  I only use boost::unordered_map::clear() function in shared_memory

Comment: You will need to create a [mcve] in order for people to be able to help you with this.